# Python 3.5 Decorators and function fields

Tags: python, function, field, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following snippet of code:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        func.var = 0
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@wrapper
def f_out():
    print(f_out.var)
```

Could you please explain to me why running `f_out()` raises:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'var'
```

**EDIT**

I had to elaborate, as an answer has given me the alternative but this will not work for the situation I want it. Given the following snippet:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        func.var = 0
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(func.var)
    return wrapped

@wrapper
def f_out():
    f_out.var = 1
f_out()
print(f_out.var)
```

I get as output:

```
0
1
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `return func` should be `return wrapped`. Does this fix it?

Comment: @RobinZigmond you are right, I will fix it, same error however

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to return the wrapped function and change it before returning it:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.var = 0
    return wrapped

@wrapper
def f_out():
    print(f_out.var)
```

You correctly get:

```
print(f_out())
```

gives

```
0
```

---

The updated snipped changes the `var` attribute twice:

- first time in the wrapper where it sets the attribute *for the original function* to 0 and prints it after calling the original function
- then when the original function is called from the wrapper, it sets the attribute *for the function referenced as `f_out`* to 1. But at that moment, the function referenced as `f_out` is the wrapped function and no longer the original one.

So when you later print `f_out.var` you print the attribute for the wrapped function which is 1.

Here is a slightly modified code demonstrating it:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.orig = func          # keeps a ref to the original function
        func.var = 0
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(func.var)
    return wrapped

@wrapper
def f_out():
    f_out.var = 1

f_out()
print(f_out.var, f_out.orig.var)
```

It prints

```
0
1 0
```

Comment: This is true, it works, but why the other does not? I updated my question

Comment: Ok, quite interesting, thank you for sharing, I had trouble to find  an answer to my query elsewhere. I somehow understand your argument about original and referenced functions, but if that stands, then the object reference to the original function is lost within the wrapper, so the fields modified inside the function body are completely inaccessible by the wrapper after the function call... Which leads me to ask, is there a way to perform a change to a function field within the function body,  which can be seen by its wrapper, so that eg to perform, or not, further computations?

Answer (score 1):

Decorator is wrapping your function when you calling it.
So when you are calling `f_out()` it returns `1`. It is wrapping function that you call, not it's definition.

```
@wrapper
def f_out()
```

equal
`wrapper(f_out)` when you call it.

When you try to print `f_out.var` it returns the value from function definition.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `return wrapped` instead if `return func` try this:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        func.var = 0
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@wrapper
def f_out():
    print(f_out.var)
```

Comment: What happens if you try calling `f_out()`?